# Make HTTP call returning an Observable after a timeout

Tags: angular, service, ngx-translate

I'm implementing @ngx-translate in our application. To fetch the translations, we use an Backend API. I have written a class with TranslationLoader (which implements the TranslateLoader) to get the translations. To make the API call, I need the access token returned by Auth0. Setting this access token by the service takes some time, and before this the TranslationLoader already places a request to the BE. This fails as the access token is missing. Could someone suggest some alternatives?

I've tried using delay and retryWhen from RxJS, but that acts on the Observable and not on the http request, so was of no use.

translation-loader

```
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private authService: AuthService, private configService: ConfigService) {}

  /**
   * The getTranslation method returns the Observables with the requested language translations
   * @param language is the string specifying which language's translation is requested.
   */
  getTranslation(language: string): Observable<any> {
    const transactionsConfig = this.configService.transactionServiceConfig;
    let authHeaderValue = {};
    try {
      if (authHeader()) {
        authHeaderValue = authHeader();
      }
    } catch {
      this.authService.logout();
    }
    return this.http.get(`${transactionsConfig.apiUrl}/dictionary/translations/ln/${language}`, {
      headers: authHeaderValue,
    })
      .pipe(
        map((result) => {
            return this.processTranslations(result);
          }
        ),
      );
  }

  processTranslations(translationCollection: object): object {
    const newObject = {};

    for (const key in translationCollection) {
      if (translationCollection.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (typeof translationCollection[key] === 'object') {
          newObject[key] = this.processTranslations(translationCollection[key]);
        } else if ((typeof translationCollection[key] === 'string') && (translationCollection[key] === '')) {
          // do not copy empty strings
        } else {
          newObject[key] = translationCollection[key];
        }
      }
    }
    return newObject;
  }
}
```

Comment: Emit a value from some observable when the euthentication ends, and use `return authObservable.pipe(first(), switchMap(() => this.http.get(...))`. So the http request won't be made until the authentication has succeeded.

Comment: The Auth service is from an external module with the app having no control over the auth status. AuthService emits an isAuthorized value, for both true and false, which renders it useless. I mostly rely on a timeout for the auth token to be set. Is there any way where I can make the HTTP call after a timeout of 1500ms, but still emit the Observable instantaneously?

Comment: Why does it make it useless? How about `authObservable.pipe(filter(authorized => authorized), first(), ...)`. But anyway, if you really want to use an ugly timeout, replace `authObservable` by `interval(1000)`.